# safe cms for shared hosting with in-place editing and end-user simplicity

Tags: content-management-system

I need an advice about a php/MySql CMS which is:

1.Safe for shared hosting. I.e. a CMS which poses no problem when it is deployed on a regular shared hosting. E.g. a CMS which requires write permissions for everybody on some folders or files is not safe in this case. Maybe there are other considerations as well. The CMS must still enable the user to upload photos etc. to his content.

2.Is dead simple from the end-user point of view, and moderately difficult from the designer/developer point of view. This includes

a) in-place editing capabilities because this is what makes it simple for the end-user

b) possibility for designer/developer to hide all CMS complexity from the user (at the price of reducing advanced features) to make it easy to use even for a dumb end-user

How about Drupal 7? AFAIK, the standard installation does not require write for everybody permissions, so it's safe. But according to the ease of use, while it has in-place editing capabilities, Drupal has no real mechanism to hide complexity from the end user, at least not that I am aware of. When clicking on the edit in-place button, the user is presented with a quite complex form to edit node, even if he has limited permissions.

How about Apostrophe Now? While it has excellent in-place editing capabilities and the end-user simplicity is really there, it requires write permissions for everybody on some folders and is not advised for shared hosting in its documentation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are much CMSs you could use which are based on php and mysql and that are:

- Joomla
- Drupal
- Wordpress

and much more

Comment: Drupal has possibilities to hide complexity from the end user. While it still has no true in-place editing (afaik they are working on it), it has contentual links, so with permission it is possible to edit content from front end, and with some tweaking, the user experience is quite good. I can't say for Wordpress or Joomla because I haven't really tried them.